# google website iframe issue

Tags: html, google-website-optimizer

please tell me how to display an external webpage in a Google website through Iframe with cookies disabled. the available gadget works fine with cookies enabled, but i need to get it working with cookies disabled.

i tried using the gadget by editing the codes. no luck with cookies disabled.
i tried inserting raw html Iframe code but it did not worked. it is just displaying a broken image.

here is the code that i inserted.

```
<iframe src="https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/home.asp?studioid=10273" style="display: block; text-align: left; margin-right: auto;" width="360" height="400">
```

but it not even working with cookies enabled.
please help me with this...

Comment: this is not iframe . this is an image , right ?

Comment: yeah sorry, its iframe. but still no luck. :(

Comment: its just showing "Cookies are required to access this site." with cookies turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely need to use their iframe gadget.

From the page you want to have the iframe, go to:

1. Edit page
2. Insert
3. More Gadgets
4. Featured
5. Include gadget (iframe)

You can then edit the properties of the iframe gadget with the URL.

**EDIT**

Found the link: http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/110044712259208757856/iframe.xml

There appear to be some negative reviews on there, but I've just tried it on Chrome 27 and it works fine.